# How to add event " onclick " to prototype of an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

i make constructor to create function carousel and i want

to add event listener ' click ' to prototype in order to inherit children . and when i create some instance inherit this properties ;

```
function Carousel(element, interval){
        this.element = document.querySelector(element);
        this.item = this.element.querySelectorAll('.item');
        this.toNext = this.element.querySelector('.right');
        this.toPrev = this.element.querySelector('.left');
        this.interval = interval;
        this.active =0;

        // Display First Element
        this.item[0].style.left = 0; 

    }

    Carousel.prototype.next = function(){
        var next;
        if (this.active === (this.item.length - 1)) {
            next = 0;
        }else{
            next = this.active + 1;
        }

        TweenMax.to(this.item[this.active], 0.8, {left:'-300px',ease:Power1.easeOut});
        TweenMax.to(this.item[next], 0.8, {left: 0, ease:Power1.easeOut});
        TweenMax.set(this.item[next], {left:'300px'})

        // Update  this.Active Position 
        this.active = next;
    }

    Carousel.prototype.prev = function() {
        var prev;
        if (this.active === 0) {
            prev = this.item.length - 1 ;
        }else{
            prev = this.active - 1;
        }

        TweenMax.set(this.item[prev], {left:'-300px'})
        TweenMax.to(this.item[this.active], 0.8, {left:'300px',ease:Power1.easeOut});
        TweenMax.to(this.item[prev], 0.8, {left: 0, ease:Power1.easeOut});

        // Update  this.active Position 
        this.active = prev;
    }
```

Comment: so, you want to do something like `this.element.addEventListener('click', ...` ?

Comment: Hi ,  thank you for caring : 
this is my pen : https://codepen.io/mh_samih/pen/gWzpNa 
i want to add event listener , when i click excute the next function in prototype .  when i add this code to constructorit excute for once 
 this.element.addEventListener('click', this.next();)